# SSH into AWS ec2 instance from another remote server?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm attempting to ssh into an AWS ec2 instance from a user on a remote server on Digital Ocean.

I uploaded the private key into the .ssh folder for the user on Digital Ocean, created a config file in in the `.ssh` directory to point to the Identity File (`.pem` file containing private key) then generated a public key via `ssh-keygen -y` and added it to the '.ssh/authorized_keys' file for the user on the ec2 instance.

My local machine connects to the ec2 instance in this way without issue & I assumed I could set up the user on the remote Digital Ocean instance in a similar manner but I am getting a `Permission denied (publickey).` error when I attempt to connect.

Verbose error output:

```
debug1: Found key in /home/temp_user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: .ssh/digital-ocean.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

`temp_user` is the new user on the Digital Ocean server. `digital-ocean.pem` is the private key created in AWS console from which the public key was generated and stored in `.ssh/authorized_keys` for the new user on the aws instance.

To test, I temporarily uploaded the private key I use on my local and

`ssh -i .ssh/local.pem <user>@<instance id>` works.

I feel like it may have to do with newly created user on the aws instance.

How can I troubleshoot or resolve this?

Comment: Why did you generate another public key when you can connect to it from your local machine? All you need is the private key to connect from anywhere.

Comment: Please paste error from verbose and commands..

Comment: @helloV The user on Digital Ocean is temporary and I didn't want to upload my local .pem file to the server.

Comment: @DonPeat Is the temp user `authorized_keys` file permission 600? If not, change it and try (or 644 as long as no write for group and world). The `.ssh` directory should have 755 permissions and be owned by the user. The authorized_keys file should have 644 permissions and be owned by the user.

Comment: No. `.ssh` directory needs execute permission, otherwise the `authorized_keys` file cannot be accessed. Change `.ssh` to 755.

Comment: @helloV The permissions for the files were correct for the user on the ec2 instance but wrong on the digital ocean user's files. Changing the permissions there did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.ssh` directory should have **755** permissions and be owned by the user. The `authorized_keys` file should have **644** permissions and be owned by the user.