# Cannot access ec2 after chmod -R 777 in root

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, connection, root, chmod

I accidentally ran "sudo chmod -R 777 ./" on my Ubuntu ec2 AWS instance. After that it kicked me out and I cannot connect to the instance anymore, neither via FTP, nor via SSH. Do you have any tip for me how I can recover my instance?

Best
John

Comment: Have you tried restarting the instance?

Comment: Yes, it did not help unfortunately

Comment: There's a possibility that sshd is refusing to start because of an insecure world-writable file. Do you have a backup that you can restore?

Comment: I guess that's the reason. Unfortunately, I didn't make a backup before running the code. Is there no other way to access the instance again? Maybe via root or so?

Comment: Unless ec2 provides some sort of backdoor then I don't believe so. You can try `nmap`ping it to make sure that everything is down. Although you might be able to download the image as a vm or disc image then manually load it up and change the files back, then load it back into an instance.

Comment: Also consider checking out [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12998/wrongly-set-chmod-777-problems) for help on restoring it.

Comment: See my answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45244254/ssh-into-aws-ec2-instance-from-another-remote-server

Answer (score 2):

Whatever directory you were in when you ran `chmod` has had the permissions for all of the files and directories that begin with a `.` recursively changed.

Since your entire system stopped working after you ran this command, I assume you were in a non-trivial directory and managed to change the permissions for some essential binaries.

As a result, they are no longer functioning correctly which has rendered your system unusable. There are three ways to recover from this. You won't like the first one. The second one probably isn't an option given your question. And the third one is really annoying to execute.

First of all, I recommend that you delete the EC2 Instance and recreate it from scratch. Maybe this time recreate your manual changes with an CaC tool like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) to make this less painful in the future. :)

If that won't work for you, then restore the filesystem from a backup or snapshot. You have those...Right? Ah, no worries. I've been there before too. Sorry about that.

Now, onto the annoying option. You might be able to recover by stopping your EC2 instance and removing the EBS disk. Then provision a new EC2 instance in the same [Availability Zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html) and [attach your old disk volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html) to it at an unused mountpoint. Power on the EC2 instance, SSH into it, [mount the old filesystem](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-mount-and-unmount-file-systems-in-linux/), and manually repair the permissions you recursively modified with `chmod`. After this, you should be able to stop that instance, add the disk back to your original instance, power it back on, and recover its state.

If you have modified a massive directory tree like `/etc/` then you're probably in really rough shape. Possibly irrecoverable with any rational amount of effort for a Linux server. However, one potential other solution you might be able to explore is using [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot).

Follow my steps above to the point where you mount the old filesystem on the new EC2 Instance. Then mount the filesystem to a space on your new filesystem and run `chroot /mnt/old/disk/location`. If you manage to change into your own filesystem, then you can hopefully automatically recover by using `apt-get` to reinstall your pacakges. `apt-get --reinstall install`. After that, simply `exit` the `chroot` session and attach the disk to your old EC2 Instance and see where that gets you.

Let me know if you need any more help. I haven't had to recover from this situation specifically before, but I have recovered from destroyed root partitions on Linux filesystems on EC2 using this process before.